# Can we get Installation and Product Prerequisites in a PDF for SDL Web 8

Tags: web8, documentation

We are working on an upgrade to SDL Web 8, We noticed that http://docs.sdl.com/ is very slow and takes lot of time to load.

Is there an option to get the Installation and Product Prerequisites on PDF format for SDL Web 8 similar to other Tridion versions? (example: SDL Tridion 2013 SP1)

Comment: Alternative: You can take Printt/Save docs page in PDF format

Comment: I already did that for few but its so slow i am not able to do. It will good if tridion provide pdf simialr to other versions. anyway thanks for the comments

Answer (score 3):

There are currently issues with https://docs.sdl.com indeed which makes it inaccessible unfortunately, it is reported and being worked on.

You may be able to get a PDF of the prerequisites via Customer Support if available.

Another option is to download the [full Web 8 documentation as HTML](https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/Distributions/?o=5886E4B4-F9F5-4869-BEDB-634329D919A8), please note this link does not contain the latest fixes of the Web 8 documentation. I'm not even sure if it is Web 8 GA or Web 8 CU1, so it is preferred to use https://docs.sdl.com when available, but for now, you at least have something.

Answer (score 1):

As Bart says in his ***answer*** - the online documentation is currently experiencing problems.

I would suggest for your **future installations / upgrades** you *prepare* in the event that online material isn't available beforehand.

Note that the second you print something / save it offline it has the potential of becoming out-of-date... but it does have the advantage of serving as a true representation of exactly what was done to complete the install.

A process I've used in the past when the client reported that online comms could be problematic was

1. Get an offline copy of the **latest** online version

   - although this may seem cumbersome to print pages as PDF and collate them *myself* it will serve the purpose of ensuring you're familiar with the process as you've gone through it 'for practice'
2. Annotate the document with known details (machine names) etc.

   - this will serve also as a prompt to ensure you've access to specific information you may require **beforehand** (such as user credentials etc.)
3. Have a final read through the documentation before storing in with your laptop

   - no matter how many installations you do, it's prudent to have a note handy as a quick reminder for those oft-forgot or more technical elements of an install, the more prepared you are the more professional you will be

In the event you have the online version available I'd still use that but then I've the printed version to make annotations on should I need to go back and check something later etc.

HTH.